# how to put try catch to an event method in order to customise the catch java

Tags: java, events, file-upload, primefaces, try-catch

I have created a method to handle uploading of files when using the `p:fileupload` tag of PrimeFaces:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException { 
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getSessionMap().put("limage", event.getFile());        
}
```

But when testing this code I get an exception:

```
 GRAVE: C:\tmp\upload_6d3af437_13dda559a63__8000_00000082.tmp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\upload_6d3af437_13dda559a63__8000_00000082.tmp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:719)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.getState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:198)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.restoreView(PrettyViewHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In order to help track down this exception, I wrapped my custom logic in a try/catch block, with a handler in the catch block that should help me determine when an exception is caught. But the catch is not being called:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException{
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
           .getExternalContext()
           .getSessionMap().put("limage", event.getFile());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("i am in catch ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

I think the problem is not in the instructions, but might be occurring before the instructions are run. Here is my UI code:

```
<p:fileUpload   mode="advanced" auto="true"
    fileUploadListener="#{articlesMB.handleFileUpload}"  />
```

How can I fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show full stacktrace?

Comment: What is your primefaces and myfaces/Mojarra versions?

Answer (score 0):

The `getFile` doesn't throw exception. The code you show just puts the file into a session map. Exception is thrown somewhere else where the file object is get used.

As I see from the stacktrace - it happens when the session tries to get deserialized between requests. You should store the file somewhere else, because the file is deleted by the framework right after multipart http request completes.

Comment: even if I comment the line of session, the exception is launched

Comment: what do you suggest me to do

Comment: Somehow your uploaded file is passed between requests. It tries to restore a view and fails, because file object holds only file name in a temp directory, but the file is deleted already.

Comment: @simonTifo Quite difficult to say, I don't see your source code. You need to locale the problem. Try to start with tutorial's upload page and see if it works.

Comment: my problem is when I upload for the first time it works, the second also but the third 50% ..., but when I use this fileupload without ajax it works, if you want I make a video to explain more the prolem or ...